# Kendo ComboBox is showing four loading gears while fetching data from server

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-combobox

Kendo ComboBox is showing four loading gears when fetching the data from the server instead of one. Is it a design or bug? How can we fix it?

Steps to reproduce:

- Visit http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/serverfiltering
- In chrome Open developer tools -> Network -> check Offline
- Now type any three characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, the background-repeat and background-position styles seem to be missing in the latest Kendo UI version. You can add them manually until the fix is applied out-of-the-box:

```
.k-i-loading,
.k-loading,
.k-loading-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```